# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception - INSERT INTO VFP9 Database

Tags: php, foxpro

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught com_exception: **Source:** ADODB.Connection
**Description:** Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SonReceipt\api\create_test.php:66
Stack trace:

1. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SonReceipt\api\create_test.php(66): com->prepare('INSERT INTO SON...')
2. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SonReceipt\api\create_test.php(35): create()
3. {main}
   thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SonReceipt\api\create_test.php on line 66

That is the error message from the php file create_test.php:

Going by the message, i think the problem area is the INSERT query but don't have a clue as the INSERT statement seems ok.

I've looked at similar 'Uncaught com_exception' posts on this forum and other sites but they are not exactly of this type. Has anyone encountered anything close to this?

TIA.

```
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// database connection
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$conn->Open("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sonreceipt\RECEIPT.DBC;Password='';Collating Sequence=MACHINE");

// get posted data
$jsonData = '{"refnum":"1111-2222-3333", "paydate":"01/06/2018", "custname":"O. A. BECKLEY VENTURES", "custemail":"beckleyventures@gmail.com", "demandno":"DEMAND NOTE 001", "demanddate":"01/06/2018", "amount":15550.00, "recpdesc":"SONCAP", "paybank":"ZENITH BANK PLC", "payref":"0123456789"}';
$data = json_decode($jsonData);

// set payment values received
$jrefnum = $data->refnum;
$jpaydate = $data->paydate;
$jcustname = $data->custname;
$jcustemail = $data->custemail;
$jdemandno = $data->demandno;
$jdemanddate = $data->demanddate;
$jamount = $data->amount;
$jrecpdesc = $data->recpdesc;
$jpaybank = $data->paybank;
$jpayref = $data->payref;

// create the payment
if (create()){
    echo "Payment was created.";
} 

// if unable to create the payment, tell the user
else {
    echo "Unable to create payment.";
}

// create payment
function create(){

    global $conn, $jrefnum, $jpaydate, $jcustname, $jcustemail, $jdemandno, $jdemanddate, $jamount, $jrecpdesc, $jpaybank, $jpayref;

    // sanitize
    $srefnum=$jrefnum;
    $spaydate=$jpaydate;
    $scustname=$jcustname;
    $scustemail=$jcustemail;
    $sdemandno=$jdemandno;
    $sdemanddate=$jdemanddate;
    $samount=$jamount;
    $srecpdesc=$jrecpdesc;
    $spaybank=$jpaybank;
    $spayref=$jpayref;

    // query to insert record
    $query = "INSERT INTO SON2100 (refnum, paydate, custname, custemail, demandno, demanddate, amount, recpdesc, paybank, payref) 
      VALUES ($srefnum, $spaydate, $scustname, $scustemail, $sdemandno, $sdemanddate, $samount, $srecpdesc, $spaybank, $spayref)";

    // prepare query
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    // execute query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        //$stmt->close();
        return true;
    } 

    return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the values you're supplying are, in fact, the right types for their respective fields. VFP is pretty strict about this. Have you tried cutting down the statement and passing only some of the fields to figure out what's giving you the error?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, the values are of the right type but on cutting down the statement and filling the values with empty strings, i discovered that the INSERT statement does not recognize the PHP variables ($variablename). Hence the uncaught com_execption: syntax error.

Comment: Still need to find a way to get the INSERT statement to accept the PHP variables in the VALUES clause.

Answer (score 0):

The error was actually caused by:

1. Not enclosing the php variables in quotes in the VALUES clause of the INSERT statement for character fields.
2. The reverse is the case for numeric fields.

Note that the values supplied to the INSERT statement are from a decoded JSON string. See the working code below.

```
?php 

// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get database connection
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$conn->Open("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sonservices\RECEIPT.DBC;Password='';Collating Sequence=MACHINE");

class Payment{

    // object properties
    public $refnum;
    public $paydate;
    public $custname;
    public $custemail;
    public $demandno;
    public $demanddate;
    public $amount;
    public $recpdesc;
    public $paybank;
    public $payref;

    // create payment
    function create(){

        global $conn;

        // convert to string values
        $this->refnum=strval($this->refnum);
        $this->paydate=strval($this->paydate);
        $this->custname=strval($this->custname);
        $this->custemail=strval($this->custemail);
        $this->demandno=strval($this->demandno);
        $this->demanddate=strval($this->demanddate);
        $this->amount=strval($this->amount);
        $this->recpdesc=strval($this->recpdesc);
        $this->paybank=strval($this->paybank);
        $this->payref=strval($this->payref);

        // query to insert record
        $query = "INSERT INTO SON2100  
            VALUES ('', '$this->refnum', '$this->paydate', '', '', '$this->custname', '$this->custemail', '$this->demandno', '$this->demanddate', $this->amount, '$this->recpdesc', '$this->paybank', '$this->payref', '')";

        // execute query
        if($conn->execute($query)){
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }   
}

// prepare payment object
$pymt = New Payment();

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set payment property values and sanitize
$pymt->refnum = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($data->refnum));
$pymt->paydate = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($data->paydate));
$pymt->custname = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($data->custname));
$pymt->custemail = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($data->custemail));
$pymt->demandno = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($data->demandno));
$pymt->demanddate = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($data->demanddate));
$pymt->amount = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($data->amount));
$pymt->recpdesc = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($data->recpdesc));
$pymt->paybank = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($data->paybank));
$pymt->payref = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($data->payref));

// create the payment
if ($pymt->create()){
    echo "Payment was created.";
}

// if unable to create the payment, tell the user
else{
    echo "Unable to create payment.";
}

?>
```